# Python package additional name

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I'm building a new PyPI [package](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) based on an existing open source project using [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and add some code modifications (they are not the same).
Example:

```
opensource-custom=2.13.1
```

Since this project requires dependencies that will look for `opensource`
what options can I pass to my `setup.py` when building my wheel files so when I do `pip freeze`/`pip list` I can see both?

```
opensource-custom=2.13.1
opensource=2.13.0
```

An example of this scenario is `intel-numpy` if you do a `pip install` of it, it will generate a copy of `numpy`.

```
>pip install intel-numpy
>pip freeze
icc-rt==2019.0
intel-numpy==1.15.1
intel-openmp==2019.0
mkl==2019.0
mkl-fft==1.0.6
mkl-random==1.0.1.1
numpy==1.15.1
tbb==2019.0
tbb4py==2019.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make `opensource` a dependency of `opensource-custom`. To do this, you can specify the `install_requires` parameter in `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='opensource-custom',
    install_requires=[
        'opensource',
    ],
    ...
)
```

See https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#install-requires

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify I build my own pypi package opensource-custom and add some modifications to it, wouldnt install_requires re-install opensource package ?

Comment: It would install it if it wasn't already installed. This is what would make it appear in `pip freeze`.

Comment: Got it, thanks do u see any option to copy package name into package manager or where pip freeze reads from?

Comment: No, the only way to do that is to install that package. Why would you want to mimic some other package? Would be very confusing to the user.